# Send data to one activity's fragment from another activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have MainActivity which contains TabLayout with tabs: each tab is a fragment and each one has a RecyclerView. When I tap FAB in Main Activity, NewReminderActivity is opened.

I use Architecture Components: Entity(Reminder), DAO, Room, ViewModel, LiveData and Repository.

The question is:

- Which methods should I use to deliver a new created reminder item into the fragment (which contains as mentioned above a RecyclerView?

I have some ideas, but could you help me please and give me a right direction for implementing:

1) I guess, I should deliver data to MainActivity, then from MainActivity to the fragment and use ViewModel as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html#sharing , am I right?

2) I guess I should use setResult() in NewReminderActivity, am I right?

Comment: I think a cleaner way would be to update the data first from NewReminderActivityViewModel to your Room database .Also subscribe your MainActivity's Fragments to listen to changes in Room database which will then automatically update your RecyclerView . 

MainActivity <-> MainActivityViewModel <-> Room Database
NewReminderActivity <-> NewReminderActivityViewModel <-> RoomDatabase
Would be glad to discuss on this further

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Room, there is no reason for you to use `setResult` to transfer new item to any of these previous Fragments/Activities, because Room manages invalidation automatically.

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ITEM")
    LiveData<List<Item>> getItemsWithChanges();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertItem(Item item);
}
```

Then

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<Item>> items;

    public LiveData<List<Item>> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public MyViewModel(MyDao myDao) {
        items = myDao.getItemsWithChanges();
    }
}
```

Then

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    MyViewModel myViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity(), viewModelFactory).get(MyViewModel.class);
        myViewModel.getItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), (items) -> {
            if(items != null) {
                adapter.submitList(items);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In which case all you need to do in your second Activity is insert the new item, then finish out:

```
// imagine this is on background thread
myDao.insertItem(item);
runOnUiThread(() -> {
    finish();
});
```

And all your RecyclerViews will update with the new item (if they are part of the results as the condition matches it).